# Why is the PMOS in NAND gate in Parallel and NMOS Series?

Tags: cmos, nmos, pmos, nand

[image]

Why is the PMOS in Parallel, and the NMOS is in series?

Comment: In a sense, because of De Morgan's law: \$\overline{A\cdot B}=\overline{A}+\overline{B}\$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static CMOS designs rely on complementary behavior of NMOS and PMOS devices.

So take a look at what will turn the top part "on" - A is 0 or B is 0. What does this do? It makes the output high.

Since the bottom part is in series, for a path to exist to ground, A and B must be 1 (NMOS - so "active high"). What does this do? It makes the output 0.

Put those combinations together:

```
A B | NAND(A,B)
--------------
0 0 |   1
0 1 |   1
1 0 |   1
1 1 |   0
```

Do you see how the portion where the output is 1 looks like it is covered by A OR B, and the combination where it is 0 is covered by the bottom half?

TA-DA! That's old-school static CMOS design!

Answer (score 0):

Do you not understand that if A *and* B are both HI (i.e. true) then Out is *not* HI, in the sense that both NMOS would be conducting and thus connecting OUT to 0?

NMOS's job is to pull LO, PMOS job is to pull HI. So the PMOS and NMOS must always be doing the opposite thing. PMOS responsds to the opposite logic levels of the NMOS. Therefore, the PMOS is arranged as the "compliment" of the NMOS.

"Compliment" being the arrangement that does the same thing but operates on inverted inputs. You change OR<->NOR and invert the inputs to get the compliment. The changing from NMOS to PMOS automatically takes care of the inverted inputs because that is the nature of PMOS and NMOS, so all you have to do is change the series connections of the NMOS to parallel for the PMOS which is the same as changing AND to OR.

AND is series-connected because NMOS 1 AND NMOS 2 must be conducting to connect the output to a voltage rail to drive the output.

OR is parallel-connected because only PMOS 1 OR PMOS 2 need to be conducting to connect the output to a voltage rail to drive it.